# How to detect that my app can't access the user's Twitter account in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, ios6

After a user has allowed my app to access their Twitter account, they can still go into the Settings App and revoke access by hitting a switch:

[image: twitter settings app]

My app needs to show the correct logged out graphics when this happens. I can do that with no problem in iOS **5** because `[TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]` returns `NO` when my app's access has been revoked. However, in iOS **6**, `canSendTweet` continues to return `YES` even after access has been revoked. So in iOS 6 my UI is in the wrong state. Is there any other way to correctly detect this in iOS 6?

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(accountStatusDidChange:)
            name:ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) accountStatusDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        NSLog(@"app can still access Twitter account in iOS 5");
        NSLog(@"always hits this path in iOS 6");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"app permission removed by user in iOS 5");
    }
}
```

By the way, the documentation on [canSendTweet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) is wrong. Twitter is not accessible anymore after you turn the switch off.

> Returns whether you can send a Twitter request.
>
> YES if Twitter **is accessible** and at least one account is set up;
>   otherwise NO. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In TWTweetComposeViewController.h

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8, it has become much easier to determine if an app has access to the user's Twitter Account(s).

**Swift**

```
ACAccountStore().accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter).accessGranted
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter] accessGranted]
```

This will return a `BOOL` that tells you whether the user gave access or not.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 6 you need to use `Social.framework`, and you can check `[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]`.

Comment: I just tried that. It is also returning true after revoking my app's access to Twitter.

Comment: After further investigation, that `isAvailableForServiceType` only returns false when the user has deleted *all* their Twitter accounts from the Settings App. So it seems to be unrelated to revoking access to individual apps.

Comment: Not working at all for me - always returns true in the iPad 6.1 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679828 
The answer basically says that this is the best way to check.

```
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                                completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted == YES) { "continue" }

             else {
                 if ([error code] == 6) { 
                     //No accounts defined
                 }
                 else if (error == nil) {
                     //Your permissions are revoked
                 }
             }
```

Comment: You should use the [ACErrorCode enum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html), not hard code 6.